# Javascript "then"ing of a member function doesn't trigger '15

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to wrap my head around javascript's *then* structure (supposably an easy way to implement promises if I understand correctly). Almost all answers I find are from years ago, and things seem to have updated significantly since then. Honestly, I am also having difficulty understanding documentation on promises and then, so I could easily be making a basic mistake.

I've got some test code as such:

```
function foo(){
   this.start = function(){
       return {
           then: function(callback){
               alert("Waiting for this to finish.");
           }
      }
   }
}
var makeItSo = new foo();
makeItSo.start().then( function() {
    alert("I waited!");
});
```

Although the "Waiting for this to finish" fires, the "I waited!" never does. What do I need to change in my foo function so that this works?

Comment: You did not call your `callback()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not invoking "callback" in your "then" function so the function that runs the "I waited" alert never runs. Try this.

```
function foo(){
   this.start = function(){
       return {
           then: function(callback){
               alert("Waiting for this to finish.");
               callback()
           }
      }
   }
}
var makeItSo = new foo();
makeItSo.start().then( function() {
    alert("I waited!");
});
```